# greatly good, great good, great by being good, great by doing good

Tags: word-usage

1. "The most common quality of **greatly good** people is generosity, and the most common quality of people who can't be **greatly good** is intolerance." — Ahsanul Irfan

There is a quote by William Shakespeare where he used the word "greatly good":

> He is not great who is not greatly good

Can I also use the word "greatly good"?

2. "The most common quality of **great good** people is generosity, and the most common quality of the people who can't be **great good** is intolerance." — Ahsanul Irfan
3. "The most common quality of people who are **great by being good** is generosity, and the most common quality of people who can't be **great by being good** is intolerance." — Ahsanul Irfan
4. "The most common quality of people who are **great by doing good** is generosity, and the most common quality of people who can't be **great by doing good** is intolerance." — Ahsanul Irfan

Comment: Shakespeare also has Fluellen (in _Henry V_) say "Yes, my conscience, he did us great good" - but here _good_ is a noun. He means that God helped the English to win the Battle of Agincourt.

Comment: @KateBunting OK, but can I use the word how I have used it? and what about my 2 and 3?

Comment: As WS2 says, _good_ is an adjective in your sentence (2), so it needs an adverb.  _Greatly good_ isn't wrong, but it isn't idiomatic in modern English. People would be more likely to say '_very_ or _extremely_ good'. (3) means that being good makes those people great - is that what you want to say?

Comment: @KateBunting I don't think "being good makes them great" OK. I have added another one (4). What about "great by doing good"

Comment: Well, that means the same as (3) - they are great because they do good.

Comment: If your question is **Can I also use the word "greatly good"?**, then yes, you can. Otherwise, I don't know what your question is asking.

Comment: If your question is *Is "greatly good" a natural "intensification" today?* then ***No! - it's not!*** Today we say ***very good***, not ***greatly good***.

Comment: To my ear, "greatly good" today would only be credible if we assume facetious wordplay alluding to *the great and the good* (important "worthy" people).

Comment: I understand what you are trying express in your *great by being good* and *great by doing good* examples but they are not idiomatically expressed within their sentences.  Your verb tenses are clashing.  It makes no sense to say, *I **am** great by doing good.*  If you **are** great, then you are great, nothing occurring concurrently can change that, including *doing good*.  I can say, *I **have become** great by doing good.*  Or I can say, *I am great by **having done** good.*  Same applies for the other example.

Comment: *I am big by eating my  vegetables,* for those who disagree and require an example.

Answer (score 0):

***Good*** is an adjective and hence would normally be qualified by an adverb, in the same way we say someone is a "thoroughly good person".

We talk of "heavily large responsibilities" etc.

There are exceptions to this, such as colours which are qualified adjectivally - "a deep purple waistband", "a limpid blue sky" etc.

Comment: I have added another sentence which is number 4. Is that OK?

Comment: @Ahsanulirfan That's ok but as Kate says the word "good" in this instance is being used as a noun, and were it being qualified (which it isn't) an adjective could be used such as "great" i.e "...by doing great good".